"orderer system channel is not defined" error after a Hyperledger Fabric 2.5 cluster reboot
I am getting this error  after a cluster reboot (Kubernetes on Azure) in a working HLF 2.5 network (deployed with Hyperledger Bevel):
channel creation request not allowed because the orderer system channel is not defined

The only information I have found online is that I can re-join the orderer nodes to the clannel using osnadmin join. Is that the correct approach to fix it? Any way to prevent this from happening again after rebooting the cluster?
